# How to do Activator.CreateInstance for various constructors?

Tags: c#

I need to get my subclasses of DataContext and I found the below function for that lying around somewhere and it sure finds my subclass but I can't instantiate it :(

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetSubclassesFor<T>(Assembly assembly)
  {
   return (assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.BaseType == (typeof (T)))
    .Select(t => (T) Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] {"asdasd"})))
    .ToList();
  }
```

I get the following error message:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   : Ett undantagsfel har inträffat i
>   målet för en aktivering.   ---->
>   System.TypeInitializationException :
>   Typinitieraren för
>   PlaynGO.Cashier.Data.CashierDC utlöste
>   ett undantag.   ---->
>   System.NullReferenceException :
>   Objektreferensen har inte angetts till
>   en instans av ett objekt. vid
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.*InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object[] args, ref
>   SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType
>   declaringType) vid
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture) vid
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) vid
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Object[] args) vid
>   PlaynGO.Dbml.Reflexion.b*_3(Type
>   t) i Reflexion.cs: line 23 vid
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   vid
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection) vid
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) vid
>   PlaynGO.Dbml.Reflexion.GetInstances(Assembly
>   assembly) i Reflexion.cs: line 23 vid
>   PlaynGO.Dbml.UnitTests.TestReflection.TestGettingTypes()
>   i TestReflection.cs: line 21
>   --TypeInitializationException vid PlaynGO.Cashier.Data.CashierDC..ctor(String
>   connection)
>   --NullReferenceException vid PlaynGO.Cashier.Data.CashierDC..cctor()

The constructor I want to call is the following:

```
    public CashierDC(string connection) :
   base(connection, mappingSource)
```

MappingSource is directly instantiated and is an instance field. Where do I go wrong? What do I have to do to make this work?

PS. This is .NET 4.0

Comment: Please try translating the error message.

Comment: LOL..  He said "do do" ... :)

Comment: Isn't the cctor the static constructor? Does it have one and if so can you post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TargetInvocationException indicates that the constructor that it is invoking has thrown an exception.  Perhaps this is due to the actual value that you are passing in for the connection string.  You might want to try using the debugger and set a break point in the constructor taking a connection string and (1) make sure that it is being invoked and (2) determine where the exception is occurring.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. You were right it was ServiceLocator problem :( I wish I had never gone down that dark path.

Answer (score 5):

I think your error is something else. If Activator.CreateInstance can't find your constructor you get a `MissingMethodException` not a `TargetInvocationException`. I suspect there's something else wrong in the actual class you're trying to instantiate.

Comment: I agree, it looks like you are getting a NullReferenceException thrown in your constructor.  If you want to double-check, run the debugger and set a breakpoint on your constructor to see if it is being called.

Comment: thank you for answering the question. It was something else and I hate myself for it right now.